# Broken NaN comparisons in x64 VS2019 - VS2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I have a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    double dNan = std::nan("nan");
    double dNotNan = 3961.12345;

    if (dNan == dNotNan)
        std::cout << "Nan == Not Nan" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Nan != Not Nan" << std::endl;   
}
```

Compiled with platform x64 with "/fp:fast" the output is:

```
Nan == Not Nan
```

With platform x86 or /fp:precise the output is the expected "Nan != Not Nan".

The assembler generated for the comparison is:

```
00007FF6F8E7101F  ucomisd     xmm0,mmword ptr [__real@40aef23f34d6a162 (07FF6F8E732B8h)]  
00007FF6F8E71027  je          main+30h (07FF6F8E71030h)
```

where __real@40aef23f34d6a162 is the 3961.12345 value, and xmm0 contains the NaN "0000000000000000-7FF8000000000000". The result of the UCOMISD instruction is that flags ZP, CF, PF are all set, which indicates "unordered", i.e. at least one of the operands is NaN. The JE instruction only tests the ZF flag, which is set to 1 when the two operands are equal.

The documentation says "Special values (NaN, +infinity, -infinity, -0.0) may not be propagated or behave strictly according to the IEEE-754 standard" with an example elsewhere given as NaN - NaN = 0, but the comparison behavior would seem to fall way outside "not strictly to standard".

I can't find any information on this; is this really the expected behaviour or have I just tripped over a compiler bug?

Comment: `/fp:strict` is computationally more expensive than `/fp:precise` because the compiler must insert additional instructions to trap exceptions and allow programs to access or modify the floating-point environment at runtime. If your code doesn’t use this capability, but requires source code ordering and rounding, or relies on special values, use `/fp:precise`.For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=vs-2019

Comment: "`/fp:fast` is intended for programs that ... do not rely on the standard rules for handling special values such as NaN." You seem to care - so don't use `/fp:fast`

Comment: @Igor Thanks; yes, it looks like that is what is going to have to happen. The problem is that changing from fast to precise not only slows down calculations (which is probably OK) but also changes the results of them in unpredictable ways (which is probably not).

Comment: @Jeaninez Yeah, what has tripped up up here is a difference in behaviour between the x86 and x64 compilers. It means that a customer can run their current 32 bit software and a new 64 bit version side by side and see differences in the output.